# Error No content provider: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <Map Container> when testing a map component jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-leaflet

I am writing a test of a component on jest that renders a map and builds a route between two points on the map. I use ReactLeaflet and leaflet routing machine. The component code is something like this:

This is not the entire component code, but a significant part of it

```
const MapLayout = ({ directionsInfo, mapUpdate }) => {
 const mapInstance = useMap;
  const project = useMemo(() => directionsInfo.project, [directionsInfo.project]);
  const surface = useMemo(() => directionsInfo.surface, [directionsInfo.surface]);

/// some code///

if (mapInstance) {
    const mapWrapperElement = document.querySelector('.map-layout');
    mapWrapperElement && mapWrapperElement.setAttribute('data-testid', 'mapWrapper');
  }
return (
    <>
      {routeIsBuilding && showRouteWindow && createPortal(<Loader />, document.querySelector('.leaflet-fullscreen-on'))}

      <MapContainer
        className="draw-toolbar map-layout"
        center={[project.lat, project.lng]}
        zoom={16}
        maxZoom={18}
        zoomControl={false}
        doubleClickZoom={false}
        attributionControl={false} // убирает надбись Leaflet в низу с права на карте
        fullscreenControl
      >
        <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
        <MapDraw
          drawOptions={{
            circle: false,
            circlemarker: false,
            marker: false,
            polygon: false,
            rectangle: false,
          }}
          editOptions={{
            edit: false,
            remove: false,
          }}
        />
        <HandlersFullscreenchange onFullscreenchange={onFullscreenchange} />
        <SetZoomOnMap />
        <CreateRouteInAlternativeMap
          _routeId={routeId}
          dataIconsForMap={dataIconsForMap}
          showItineraryDescription={showRouteWindow}
        />
        {showRouteWindow && <RouteWindow routeId={routeId} />}
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};
}
```

Test code:

```
import MapLayout from '../pages/Layout/MapLayout';

it('Проверяем что карта в макетах отрисовалась', () => {
  const initialState = {
    mapSearch: {
      zoom: 5,
      dataRoutes: [],
    },
  };

  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);

    const mapLayout = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MapLayout directionsInfo={directionsInfo} mapUpdate={false} />
    </Provider>
  );

  render(mapLayout);

  expect(screen.getByTestId('mapWrapper')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

When running the test, I get the error No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of .

Naturally, there is no such error while the application is running. I'm new to tests. There are suspicions that somewhere something is not a lock but on. But I don't understand where and what. I ask you to throw ideas. I will look for an error by the exclusion method)). Thank you in advance.

I also tried creating a LeafletContext and wrapping it around a component in the test. And it doesn't help either. It seems to me that the problem is not in the component but in the test environment